# Menu driven palindrome tester getting stack Overflow error

Tags: menu, console, stack-overflow, palindrome

I'm doing this for a class, and I'm really not terribly awesome at this as I'm over a decade out of  practice. I'm trying to write a program that displays a menu so the user can choose between methods of determining if it's a palindrome.

It then needs to redisplay the menu once it has completed the test.  I'm getting a stack overflow error in the isPalindrome method since I combined the 2 classes into one class, which I thought would fix another problem I was having with the output!  Any thoughts or directions I can take?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PalHelper 
{
public String pal;
public void MenuList() 
{
System.out.println("How would you like to check your phrase?");
System.out.println("1. Check the first letter like it's the last letter - Leave no phrase unturned!");
System.out.println("2. I Prefer my Palindromes have the gentle treatment");
System.out.println("3. We're done here");
System.out.print("Selection: ");
}

public PalHelper() 
{
Scanner decision = new Scanner(System.in);
    MenuList();

switch (decision.nextInt()) 
{
    //to access the character by character method of determination
    case 1:
    System.out.print("Enter Phrase to Test, the Hard Way:");
    Scanner keyboard1 = new Scanner(System.in); //declares scanner variable for user entry
    String UserInput1 = keyboard1.next();//Phrase variable
    Boolean test1 = isPalindrome(UserInput1);
            if (test1 == true){
                System.out.println(UserInput1+" is a palindrome. That doesn't make you smart.");    
                        }
            else {
                System.out.println(UserInput1+" is a not palindrome. Why don't you think a little harder and try again.");
                        }
    System.out.println("..\n..\n..\n");
    keyboard1.close();
    new MenuList();
    break;

    //to access the string buffer method of determination
    case 2:
    System.out.print("Thank you for choosing the gentle way, please enter your phrase:");
    Scanner keyboard2 = new Scanner(System.in); //declares scanner variable for user entry
    String UserInput2 = keyboard2.next();
    Boolean test2 = isPalindrome2(UserInput2);
    if (test2 == true){
                System.out.println(UserInput2+" is a palindrome. Congratulations! You are so wonderful!");  
                    }
            else {
                System.out.println(UserInput2+" is a not palindrome. It's ok, I'm sure you'll get it next time.");
                    }
    System.out.println("..\n..\n..\n");
    keyboard2.close();
    new MenuList();
    break;

//exit menu
    case 3:
    System.out.println ( "Too bad – I hid a boot!" );    
    break;

//response to input other than 1,2,3
    default:
    System.out.println ( "No sir! Away! A papaya war is on." );
    System.out.println("..\n..\n..\n");
    new MenuList();
    break;

    }// close switch
}//close pal helper




public void Palindrome(String UserInput) {

}

public boolean isPalindrome(String UserInput) {
pal = UserInput.toUpperCase();   
if (pal.length() <= 1) {//one character, automatically a palindrome
   return true;     
}

char start = pal.charAt(0);
char end = pal.charAt(pal.length()-1);
        if (Character.isLetter(start) &&
            Character.isLetter(end)) {//check if first and last characters match

            if (start != end) {
                return false;     //if the beginning & ending characters are not the same it's not a palindrome      
            }
            else {

            Palindrome subpal = new Palindrome(pal.substring(1,pal.length()-1));
            return subpal.isPalindrome();  //check middle dropping start and end letters
            }
        }
        else if (!Character.isLetter(start)) {
            Palindrome subpal = new Palindrome(pal.substring(1));
            return subpal.isPalindrome(pal);      //check if first letter is a letter, drop if not
        }
        else {
            Palindrome subpal = new Palindrome(pal.substring(0,pal.length()-1));
            return subpal.isPalindrome(pal);      //check if first letter is a letter, drop if not
        }                       

}//close isPalindrome
public boolean isPalindrome2(String UserInput){

 pal = UserInput.toUpperCase();
 pal = pal.replaceAll("\\W", "");//gets rid of space and punctuation
 StringBuffer check = new StringBuffer(pal);//reverses pal string and creates new stringbuffer for check
 check.reverse();


        if (check.toString().equals(pal)){//checks for equality between pal and it's reverse
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

  }//close isPalindrome2

public static void main (String[]args) 
{
new PalHelper();

}//close main
}//close class
```

Comment: Can you add in the actual error message, that could help.

Comment: This doesn't look like the code you are running. It has syntax errors, and references a class `Palindrome` that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from my comment above, there is a problem that I noticed: in some cases, you construct a new Palindrome instance with the substring, but pass the full string while recursing to the `isPalindrome()` method. This causes the recursion to never terminate (which also makes your code hard to follow).

Comment: Thanks!  I'm sorry, I'm really out of practice and my school wouldn't let me retake CS1 so, I'm massively struggling to understand where we are.  The lack of book isn't helping! I had Palindrome as a separate class, but I was getting issues when I ran it, option 2 would run fine, but option 1 would only display AFTER option 2 had run.

How would I correct the recursion issue on isPalindrome()?

Comment: I'd say, get rid of creating new instances of `Palindrome`, and pass the substrings you pass to the constructor to the `isPalindrome` method call instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your example is missing something, the following line has missing closing brackets:

   Palindrome subpal = new Palindrome(pal.substring(1,pal.length()-1);
2. Your comments dont seem to match the code:

   return subpal.isPalindrome(pal);      //check if first letter is a letter, drop if not
3. Try adding Output to the Method `isPalindrome()` or debug it. You are probably not calling it with the right Strings and end up looping over the same Strings over and over.

   public boolean isPalindrome(String UserInput) {
       System.out.println(UserInput);
       ...

Edit: If your code really is exaclty like you posted then vhallac is right, you call `isPalindrome()` with the full String.

Comment: 1. Oh! Thanks, I tried to rewrite those and since all the errors were on those lines I missed putting the ) back in!
2. Thanks - I rearranged some things so I'll fix the comments
3. Just put in a return on the method and add the (String UserInput) to all the instances of it? 
I'm sorry, I am really bad at this!

Comment: Changed it over to this-still won't go

    else {
        //check middle dropping start and end letters
        String subpal = pal.substring(1,pal.length()-1);
    return subpal.isPalindrome(pal);  
       }
   }
   else if (!Character.isLetter(start)) {
    //check if first letter is a letter, drop if not
    String subpal = new pal.substring(1);
       return subpal.isPalindrome(pal);      
   }
   else {
    //check if first letter is a letter, drop if not
    String subpal = new pal.substring(0,pal.length()-1);
       return subpal.isPalindrome(pal);      
   }